# Laravel Query Builder - Date Query not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

i am looping whole month using `for loop`

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $days; $i++) {
     $date = now()->format('Y-m-') . $i; //result '2020-08-1'
     $date = Carbon::parse($date); //parsing with carbon
     $profit = Profit::whereDate('created_at', $date->format('Y-m-d'))->first(); //<-- this not working getting null data
     $data[] = $profit;
}
```

but this working

```
$profit = Profit::whereDate('created_at', '2020-08-01')->first(); //<-- its working fine statically
```

what i am doing wrong help me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I have to believe we are missing a piece of the puzzle.

That being said, you don't need to work that hard to query by date in Laravel: the query builder will accept Carbon dates no problem. So I would suggest we simplify your code to this, and see if it changes anything:

```
$date = Carbon::today()->startOfMonth(); // This is the first day of today's month, i.e. 2020-08-01
for($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    $profit = Profit::whereDate('created_at', $date)->first();
    $data[] = $profit;
    $date->addDay();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but still don't know why its was not working

Comment: The new code works though? Aside from being a bit more efficient, it should amount to the same SQL query as yours... Very weird. Have you tried inspecting the SQL of your old way of doing things? i.e. Profit::whereDate('created_at', $date->format('Y-m-d'))->toSql() ?